# Export FBX with shape keys and animations takes FOREVER?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, export, unity, .fbx

Ok, I am following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Zqy5GhUV-Q just trying to export my skapekeys/animations in FBX from Blender (going to Unity).

Granted my mesh has a lot of parts and I had total 6 animations, but it has been loading for the past 2 min now. Did I do something wrong? I'm on a Mac and blender 2.79, cycles.

How can I reduce this export time? Im not even sure it's going through at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Try 'Selected Objects only' - on my machine, Blender hangs for tens of minutes if this isn't selected as it tries to export every object's animation *for every object* recursively.